# AngularJs: ng-bind not working when I am using a function in the variable and return some text

Tags: angularjs

Angular it is returning something strane.

I have this controller:

```
app.controller('indexViewController', ['LocalizationHandler', function (LocalizationHandler) {
    var self = this;        

    self.Nombre = function ()    {
        return "asdfasdf";
    };    
}]);
```

in html I have:

```
<body ng-controller="indexViewController as IndexVM">
...
<span ng-bind="IndexVM.Nombre"></span>
...
</body>
```

In screen I have this:

```
function () { return "foo"; };
```

what do I have to do to see the text of Nombre?

Comment: What I see in screen it is function in one line not in three lines as you suggested. Don't chagnge it please again because won't be true your change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got execute the function! (Invoke it via `()`)

```
ng-bind="IndexVM.Nombre()"
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexVM.Nombre is a function, when put in your ng-bind Angular will display it as a string with your code inside.

Now IndexVM.Nombre() is the result of your function. This will give you what you expected

```
<span ng-bind="IndexVM.Nombre()"></span>
```